# Error : "The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher."

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle

I have been facing this error: **FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.** with **flutter_launch :^0.2.0**.
I have tried every similar solution found on net but I was unable to resolve it. I am new to flutter and any kind of help would be really appreciated. The error is:

> The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
>   The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
>   project ':flutter_launch' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71

My app\build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.4"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.7'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72"
}
```

And my android\build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
```